# How to authenticate users through Angular 2+ / NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication

I'm using a web API that receives http get requests and return json data coming from a mySQL database.

The http url return all users (http://localhost:3000/api/users)

The data arrives like this:

[image]

How can I authenticate users with Angular 2+ using this data?

Comment: You need to learn about [**Guards**](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/router-guards/) in angular, and use the user's data to create authentication tokens and store it at browser's **localStorage**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the list of "allUsers" in local storage. However you shouldn't return the user set in 1st place.

Then take user credential from login page, and compare it to data being present in the 'allUsers' collection.

Angular guards can allow authorization once you have identified a user as valid. For that, you need to send the logged in user details to security database and identify correct roles. But first you must authenticate as above.